# How to prevent a macro from executing in hidden cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro to replace special characters with HTML entities, and I would like this macro to apply only to unhidden cells.

I have tried the `Hidden` property, but I am just too new to VBA and don't know how to use it for this.

So far my code is:

```
Sub replaceTextWithHTML()

Cells.Replace What:="–", Replacement:="&ndash;", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

[other similar replacements]

End Sub
```

When run in a workbook which contains hidden rows, columns or sheets, the macro modifies their contents, too. I would like the macro to only edit visible contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cell is hidden if its column or row is hidden:

```
Sub hgfds()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False And cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
            cell.Replace what:="-", replacement:="&ndash"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much. That will definitely be useful in many occasions!

Answer (score 0):

u can try

```
For Each cells In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   Cells.Replace What:="–", Replacement:="&ndash;", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Next cells
```

it checks each cell if visible or not. it could take some time to run...

Comment: Hi Luis, thank you for your help. Unfortunately this didn't work—that or I didn't apply it correclty.